# Mostrar membro com id mesma coluna

Tags: php, mysql

Como que eu faço para exibir uma lista de membros de cada cargo, sendo que alguns membros estão em mais de um cargo. As categorias onde os membros se encontram, estão na mesma coluna separados por pipe (`|`).

Segue a imagem abaixo:
[image: -]

O meu código só exibe o primeiro `id` (8) por exemplo, no caso se eu clicar em outro cargo, como por exemplo no `id` 40, ele não aparece no site.
Segue o meu código:

```
<?php
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
$newid = ($id."|");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acp_usuarios u, acp_cargos t WHERE t.id=u.cargos AND u.id=t.user_id AND u.status='Ativo' AND u.ativado='s' AND u.cargos LIKE '$newid' OR u.cargos = '$newid' ORDER BY u.id");
while($ver = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal é reformular o banco de dados e criar uma tabela para associar o cargo com o usuário. Mas se não for possível fazer essa reformulação, você pode driblar esse problema da seguinte forma:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acp_usuarios u, acp_cargos t WHERE t.id=u.cargos AND u.id=t.user_id AND u.status='Ativo' AND u.ativado='s' AND (u.cargos LIKE '%|$id|%' OR u.cargos LIKE '%|$id' OR u.cargos LIKE '$id|%') ORDER BY u.id");
while($ver = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

}
```

O problema de fazer dessa forma é que vai perder a velocidade da consulta.

Answer (score 2):

```
LIKE '%$newid%'
```

Os % indica em que posição tu tá procurando o resultado, quando tu usa %$newid% nos diz que tu está procurando pelo valor da variável em qualquer posição da coluna.

Leitura recomendada:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp